# Ranking with a match function in R?

Tags: r

I've got the following set of data:

```
     Date  Team 1   Team 2  Team 3  Team 4  Team 5  Team 6
25-Sep-18   17  9   11  14  19  9
24-Sep-18   18  3   2   19  16  5
21-Sep-18   15  11  4   11  9   5
20-Sep-18   1   12  13  18  11  2
19-Sep-18   10  5   6   16  16  13
18-Sep-18   1   13  1   18  5   2
17-Sep-18   16  3   1   13  18  11
14-Sep-18   6   9   18  17  17  1
13-Sep-18   8   4   19  17  4   10
12-Sep-18   6   13  14  6   12  14
11-Sep-18   15  7   9   12  4   3
10-Sep-18   3   11  11  2   5   19
7-Sep-18    1   17  13  9   18  1
```

I can rank the Team columns and determine what the largest value is, but I'm having trouble creating another data frame that has the largest value and also the corresponding date, eg:

```
Team Name Date  Result
Team 1  24-Sep  18
Team 2  7-Sep   17
Team 3  13-Sep  19
Team 4  24-Sep  19
Team 5  25-Sep  19
Team 6  10-Sep  19
```

I can't work out from reading the forums whether it would be best to rank them and then use a match function to get the date, or whether I should be looking to identify the index position of the largest value and then use that to create the new frame?

(As you can probably tell, I'm really lost at the moment - I'm sure there's an easier solution than what I'm playing with and was hoping someone might point me in the right direction).

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R approach:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(paste0("Team", 1:6), function(x) {
    #for each team x, find the row that has the largest score
    n <- which.max(df[,x])

    #extract the columns that you want
    data.frame(Team=x, Date=df$Date[n], Result=df[n, x])
}))
```

output:

```
   Team      Date Result
1 Team1 24-Sep-18     18
2 Team2  7-Sep-18     17
3 Team3 13-Sep-18     19
4 Team4 24-Sep-18     19
5 Team5 25-Sep-18     19
6 Team6 10-Sep-18     19
```

Or a `data.table` approach:

```
library(data.table)
mDT <- melt(setDT(df), id.vars="Date", variable.name="Team", value.name="Result")
mDT[mDT[, .I[which.max(Result)], by=.(Team)]$V1]
```

output:

```
        Date  Team Result
1: 24-Sep-18 Team1     18
2:  7-Sep-18 Team2     17
3: 13-Sep-18 Team3     19
4: 24-Sep-18 Team4     19
5: 25-Sep-18 Team5     19
6: 10-Sep-18 Team6     19
```

data:

```
df <- read.table(text="Date  Team1   Team2  Team3  Team4  Team5  Team6
25-Sep-18   17  9   11  14  19  9
24-Sep-18   18  3   2   19  16  5
21-Sep-18   15  11  4   11  9   5
20-Sep-18   1   12  13  18  11  2
19-Sep-18   10  5   6   16  16  13
18-Sep-18   1   13  1   18  5   2
17-Sep-18   16  3   1   13  18  11
14-Sep-18   6   9   18  17  17  1
13-Sep-18   8   4   19  17  4   10
12-Sep-18   6   13  14  6   12  14
11-Sep-18   15  7   9   12  4   3
10-Sep-18   3   11  11  2   5   19
7-Sep-18    1   17  13  9   18  1", header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tidyverse approach:

```r
library(tidyverse)
tmp <- data.table::fread(
"     Date  Team_1   Team_2  Team_3  Team_4  Team_5  Team_6
25-Sep-18   17  9   11  14  19  9
24-Sep-18   18  3   2   19  16  5
21-Sep-18   15  11  4   11  9   5
20-Sep-18   1   12  13  18  11  2
19-Sep-18   10  5   6   16  16  13
18-Sep-18   1   13  1   18  5   2
17-Sep-18   16  3   1   13  18  11
14-Sep-18   6   9   18  17  17  1
13-Sep-18   8   4   19  17  4   10
12-Sep-18   6   13  14  6   12  14
11-Sep-18   15  7   9   12  4   3
10-Sep-18   3   11  11  2   5   19
7-Sep-18    1   17  13  9   18  1"
)

df.tmp <- tmp %>%
  mutate(Date = lubridate::as_date(Date,format = "%d-%b-%y",tz="")) %>%
  gather(starts_with("Team"),key= "team_name",value = "Results") %>%
  group_by(team_name) %>%
  top_n(n = 1, wt = Results) %>%
  arrange(team_name)

df.tmp
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#> # Groups:   team_name [6]
#>   Date       team_name Results
#>   <date>     <chr>       <int>
#> 1 2018-09-24 Team_1         18
#> 2 2018-09-07 Team_2         17
#> 3 2018-09-13 Team_3         19
#> 4 2018-09-24 Team_4         19
#> 5 2018-09-25 Team_5         19
#> 6 2018-09-10 Team_6         19
```

<sup>Created on 2018-09-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` approach.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)

# Create fake dataset.
dt <- data.table(Date = paste0("Date", 1:10), Team1 = rnorm(10), Team2 = rnorm(10), Team3 = rnorm(10), Team4 = rnorm(10), Team5 = rnorm(10), Team6 = rnorm(10))

# Change format of fake dataset.
longDT <- melt(dt, id.vars = "Date", variable.name = "Team", value.name = "Result")

# Get the dates with the highest result for each team.
maxDate <- longDT[, list(MaxDate = Date[which.max(Result)]), by = Team]

# Inner join `longDT` and `maxDate` to retrieve the desired output.
want <- merge(longDT, maxDate, by.x = c("Date", "Team"), by.y = c("MaxDate", "Team"))
setorder(want, Team)
setcolorder(want, c("Team", "Date", "Result"))
want

    Team  Date    Result
1: Team1 Date3 1.9220531
2: Team2 Date6 0.7487642
3: Team3 Date3 1.4940476
4: Team4 Date1 2.0749170
5: Team5 Date1 0.9347443
6: Team6 Date2 1.0755934
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's 2 line, single chain solution using `tidyr` -

```
library(tidyr)

gather(df, key = "Team", value = "value", Team1:Team6) %>%
  .[ave(.$value, .$Team, FUN = function(x) x == max(x)) > 0, ]

# Date  Team value
# 2  24-Sep-18 Team1    18
# 26  7-Sep-18 Team2    17
# 35 13-Sep-18 Team3    19
# 41 24-Sep-18 Team4    19
# 53 25-Sep-18 Team5    19
# 77 10-Sep-18 Team6    19
```

---

Data -

```
df <- read.table(text="Date  Team1   Team2  Team3  Team4  Team5  Team6
25-Sep-18   17  9   11  14  19  9
                 24-Sep-18   18  3   2   19  16  5
                 21-Sep-18   15  11  4   11  9   5
                 20-Sep-18   1   12  13  18  11  2
                 19-Sep-18   10  5   6   16  16  13
                 18-Sep-18   1   13  1   18  5   2
                 17-Sep-18   16  3   1   13  18  11
                 14-Sep-18   6   9   18  17  17  1
                 13-Sep-18   8   4   19  17  4   10
                 12-Sep-18   6   13  14  6   12  14
                 11-Sep-18   15  7   9   12  4   3
                 10-Sep-18   3   11  11  2   5   19
                 7-Sep-18    1   17  13  9   18  1", header=TRUE)
```